# How can I make struct variables inaccessible to change from default value when using default initialization?

Tags: rust, default, private-members

I want to use default initialization for *some*, but not all member variables of a struct. Is there a way to do it? This code gives me an error. It seems I need all variables being public in order to use Default::default.

```
pub struct Thing {
    pub a: u32,
    pub b: u16,
    c: f64, // <- I want to hide this variable from outside
}

impl Default for Thing {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Thing {
            a: 0,
            b: 0,
            c: 1.0,
        }
    }
}
```

So when I use this struct from outside I want to be able to do this:

```
let my_thing = thing::Thing { a: 1, ..Default::default() }
```

But I want to prevent this:

```
let my_thing = thing::Thing { c: 3.1415, ..Default::default() }
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen `default` used like this :D didn't know this syntax is a thing.

Comment: Yes, it's very cool! normally you can also just use #[derive(Default)] and the compliment fills in the default values of each of the used types.

Comment: I'm afraid, though, that as soon as you have private variables, you can't use `Thing{ .. }` in general any more to construct an item. You need to utilize constructor methods. But I'm not 100% sure on it, so I'm just posting it here as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @Finomnis is correct. See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ccba9dc34b1f60d4518139f51930ce62)

Comment: @apilat I assume OP knows this, I think he is asking if there is a way to achieve this anyway. I have a suspicion that there isn't, but I'm not 100% sure.